# Where should i'll find the model "sale.order" code in Odoo 11

Tags: orm, odoo

please guide me how can i see the actual code of sale.order as i have seen many times the

```
_inherit = 'sale.order'
```

I have gone through the github url "https://github.com/odoo/odoo/" but didn't ablelto find actual base model code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original model `sale.order` is declared in the `sale` module, folder `models`, file `sale.py`.

Github path: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py

You can easily find the definition of any model looking for the following regular expression in your Odoo folder:

```
_name\s?=\s?.your.model.name.
```

And if you filter the searching to look only in *.py* files, it will be quicker.

Comment: can you share the github path